# material-ui, component does not work

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I looked the code on http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button.

When I does not use the material-ui, the `Nav` work well.

> 5:8   warning  'RaisedButton' is defined but never used    no-unused-vars
>     15:11  warning  'style' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
>     22:10  error    'MuiThemeProvider' is not defined           react/jsx-no-undef
>     22:37  error    'muiTheme' is not defined                   no-undef
>     26:14  error    'RaiseButton' is not defined                react/jsx-no-undef
>     26:39  warning  Style prop value must be an object          react/style-prop-object
>     27:14  error    'RaiseButton' is not defined                react/jsx-no-undef
>     27:39  warning  Style prop value must be an object          react/style-prop-object

```
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

class Nav extends Component {
  render () {
    const style = {
      margin: 12,
    };
    return (
        <nav>
            <RaiseButton label="机构管理" style="{style}"  containerElemet={<Link to="/"></Link>} />
            <RaiseButton label="报名成员" style="{style}" containerElemet={<Link to="/apply"></Link>} />
            <RaiseButton label="全部成员" style="{style}"  containerElemet={<Link to="/driftMember"></Link>}/>
            <RaiseButton label="全部成员" style="{style}" containerElemet={<Link to="/allMember"></Link>}/>
            <RaiseButton label="文案设置" style="{style}" containerElemet={<Link to="/textSet"></Link>} />
        </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. It's "Raised" Button, not "Raise".

**EDIT:**

Also, note that 
style="{style}" should be style={style} without the quotes

and containerElemet should be containerElement (you missed the **n**)